# Problems with Finding the Longest word in a Data File

Tags: java

Sounds Pretty Straightforward, but for me it's quite strange. I'm trying to import a data file (which I've done successfully), and use this and compare each and every word to see which one is the longest. So far, it is not working (index out of bounds), and when I did manipulate it to work (incorrectly), it gave me the wrong word as the longest one.

This is what I have so far...

Main File:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

import static java.lang.System.*;

public class FancyWordsRunner

{
    private static int max = 0;
    public static void main( String args[] ) throws IOException
    {
        ArrayList<String> wordList = new ArrayList<String>();
            {

                String ray = "";
                    Scanner welcome = new Scanner(new File("fancywords.dat"));
                    while(welcome.hasNext())
                    {
                        ray = welcome.next();
                        wordList.add(ray);

                        for(int i = 0; i<wordList.size(); i++)
                         {
                            int j = i+1;
                                if(wordList.get(j).length()>wordList.get(i).length())
                                max = j;
                        }
                    }

                    }
                    String maximum = wordList.get(max);
                    out.println(maximum);
        }       
}
```

fancywords.dat:

```
2013 UIL STATE CONTEST
PROGRAMMING IS FUN
TODAY IS SATURDAY
```

Current Output:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
    at java.util.ArrayList.RangeCheck(ArrayList.java:547)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:322)
    at FancyWordsRunner.main(FancyWordsRunner.java:35)
```

Comment: Look carefully at your `for` loop.  Inside, you are comparing each thing in the list (`wordList.get(i)`) with the following thing in the list (`wordList.get(j)`).  This is going to pick up all cases where a word is longer than the one before it - it's not going to distinguish the maximum one.  Moreover, when `wordList.get(i)` is the last entry in the list, `wordList.get(j)` is past the end of the list, so it will give you an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Comment: @Beginning Java, you really don't need a List to perform this task.  You're just making your life more difficult.  Unless, this is an assignment that requires you to use a List, for learning purposes, You don't need it. Check my answer below for alternative.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i<wordList.size(); i++)
    {
        int j = i+1;
```

You're setting up your `for` loop to make sure `i` is never out of bounds, but then you set `j` equal to one larger than `i`, so on the last run of the loop, when `i` is at the last index, `j` is one larger than the last index (and out of bounds).

Try this:

```
for(int i=0; i<(wordList.size()-1); ++i)
```

---

Solution to the logic error:

```
for(int i = 0; i<wordList.size();++i) {
    if(wordList.get(i).length() >= wordList.get(max).length()) {
        max = i;
   }
}
```

(This also gets rid of the `j` that was causing the `IndexOutOfBoundsException` in the first place.)

---

And as others have pointed out, there is some redundancy in your program.  Changing your `for` loop to my suggestion will fix your logic problem and make your program output the correct result.  The other answers all get rid of the `ArrayList`, which isn't totally necessary, but if you want to simplify your solution and keep the `ArrayList`, your `while` loop could look something like this:

```
String longestWord = "";
Scanner welcome = new Scanner(new File("fancywords.dat"));
while(welcome.hasNext()) {
    ray = welcome.next();
    wordList.add(ray);

    if(ray.length() > longestWord.length()) {
        longestWord = ray;
    }

}
```

This solution simplifies your answer, saves some time in the program and keeps the `ArrayList` (you still have every word saved in memory).

Your `for` loop was running a LOT and checking every word numerous times.  Once we know that `CONTEST` is the longest of the first four words, we don't need to see whether `PROGRAMMING` is longer than the first three or not, just whether it's longer than `CONTEST`, and we don't need to compare `SATURDAY` to any word other than `PROGRAMMING`, which was established as the longest word when it was read and continued to be the longest word between then and reading `SATURDAY`, etc.  If all we care about is the longest word, we only need to compare each word to the current longest word.

And because your `ArrayList` is still in memory, you can recreate the original words you read in, find the shortest word, find the average word length, etc., whatever you want to do with it.

Comment: This solved the overflow error, but now it prints "SATURDAY" instead of "PROGRAMMING" like it should be.

Comment: @BeginningJava That's because you're only comparing each word to the word before it... I included the logic fix in my answer now.

Answer (score 0):

In your first iteration, you've only added one item to the list, so the size is 1 meaning only an index of 0;

```
int j = i+1;
if(wordList.get(j)
```

This is trying to access index 1

Walk through:

```
1)
 ArrayList<String> wordList = new ArrayList<String>();
 // wordlist.size() = 0;  available indices - none

2)
 wordList.add(ray);
 // wordlist.size() = 1; available indices - 0

3)
 int j = i+1;   // i = 0; j = 1
 if(wordList.get(j)  // access index j
 // oops!; There is no index j
```

This causes an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

**EDIT: Alternative - you really don't need a list to perform this task**

```
String maxWord = "";
String current = "";

while(welcome.hasNext()){
    current = welcome.next();

    if (current.length() > maxWord.length()){
        maxWord = current;
    }
}

System.out.println(maxWord);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about replacing your `while` loop with something like this.

```
String longestSoFar = "";
while (welcome.hasNext()) {
    String current = welcome.next();
    if (current.length() > longestSoFar.length()) {
        longestSoFar = current;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I realize that your bug has been identified by other answers, but, you do realize that this problem can be solved in a much simpler way?

```
public static void main( String args[] ) throws IOException {
    String max = "";
    Scanner welcome = new Scanner(new File("fancywords.dat"));
    while(welcome.hasNext()) {
        String ray = welcome.next();
        if (ray.length() > max.length()) {
            max = ray;
        }
    }       
    System.out.println(max);
}
```